# How does mongoose know which ids are taken when assigning id to new document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I noticed that when I create a new instance of the model object in mongoose (instances of model objects are called documents) the _id is assigned before saving to the database. Because creating a new document doesn't take a callback function, I don't think it communicates with database while creating new document. So, my question is how does mongoose know that it is not using an id that is already taken by some document in the database. Also I noticed that unless the server restarts the _id just increments by 1 every time a new document is created. my guess is that a random number is generated every time the server is started and is incremented by 1 for every document created.

Answer (score 1):

All MongoDB drivers (aka client libraries) will generate object IDs directly on the client. One of my colleagues Ken Alger has done a complete write up [here](https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/bson-data-types-objectid). In essence the driver generates the ID without reference to the server. It uses a combination of a timestamp, a random value and count to guarantee that all the object IDs in a given collection are unique.

This is a function of the underlying driver rather than Mongoose. You can override generation of this value by providing your own `_id` value to any document you insert. The only constraint is that because `_id` has a unique index applied automatically all inserted IDs must be unique or the insert will be rejected.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html